# Using data from csv file as vector of characters in R

Tags: r, vector

I am new to R and am trying to use the [SocialMediaMineR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SocialMediaMineR/index.html) package to resolve shortened URLs that I have stored in a csv dataset. This is done with the command get_url, which requires a vector of characters as the URLs to be resolved.

Let us say I want to resolve three URLS. If I manually create a vector with those three characters and launch the command, it works:

```
    library(SocialMediaMineR)
    url<- c("http://buff.ly/1bH9XaL", "http://buff.ly/1I4REcx", "http://buff.ly/1kMqoFs")
    get_url(url, return.df = T)
...             originalURL
1 http://buff.ly/1bH9XaL
2 http://buff.ly/1I4REcx
3 http://buff.ly/1kMqoFs
                                                                                                                                                                                         resolvedURL
1                                     https://www.storiedmind.com/relationship/11-relationship-traps-of-depression/?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffer8151c&utm_medium=twitter
2 http://inkygirl.com/inkygirl-main/2015/8/15/am-going-to-try-hard-not-to-be-like-these-writers-while-im-o.html?utm_content=bufferc6643&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer
3         http://the7gracesofmarketing.com/2014/07/10-business-systems-to-help-your-one-person-enterprise-grow/?utm_content=buffer83b26&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer
```

However, I would like the list of URLs to be taken directly from my csv file. I tried the following code with a csv file that contains the exact same three URLs as before:

```
library(SocialMediaMineR)
url_list = read.csv("~/Desktop/url2.csv", header = F)
as.character(url_list)
get_url(url_list)
```

But, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

For clarity, here is the structure of the data as read from the csv file:

```
> url_list<-read.csv("~/Desktop/url2.csv", header = F)
> dput(url_list)
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("http://buff.ly/1bH9XaL", 
"http://buff.ly/1I4REcx", "http://buff.ly/1kMqoFs"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(url_list)` just after `read.csv`? (Before any other instruction.)

Comment: Please show intermediate results. What is the structure of `url_list` when you import the data through `read.csv`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have added the info to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have added the info to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you haven't read the data using argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, so you have a column of objects of class `factor`. You must therefore do

```
url_list$V1 <- as.character(url_list$V1)
```

After this the following seems to work.

```
get_url(url_list$V1)
```

Note: The proper way of reading in the data would have been, like I've said above,

```
url_list = read.csv("~/Desktop/url2.csv", header = F, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This does it!